# Internet download speed dropped down hugely, upload speed fine

Tags: windows, lan, bandwidth, isp

I'm having a 10 Mbps LAN connection and it used to work ok, but since yesterday the download speed has been terribly low. I'm getting 266 kbps, BUT the upload speed is great - almost 10 mbps.

I've contacted the ISP and they say there's nothing on their side, so I've tried a bunch of stuff:

- restarted router, including restarting from the admin panel and
  powering off for a minute
- restarted pc
- connected directly to WAN with a laptop, which was fully formatted a few days ago and now has a 100% clean OS
- tried to check speed from Windows secure mode
- checked to see if anyone is stealing Wi-Fi and it doesn't look like that

None of these helped and I'm still at soul tormentingly slow download speed and good upload speed. Please help.

Comment: Ask your ISP whether they use a switch or hub for you connection and what's the uplink bandwidth. You might be competing with others on the same switch/hub. Many consumer ISPs don't have a minimum download bandwidth guarantee though.

Comment: What version of Windows?